# Passing Values from React form to Controller and displaying result

Tags: c#, reactjs

I have a question about using react with a function I set up in C# that has a controller to get values via the URL.

This is the Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{number}/{source}/{aux}/{destination}")]
    public string Get(int number, string source, string aux, string destination)
    {
        Hanoi h = new Hanoi();
        return h.MoveDisks(number, source, aux, destination);
    }
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script type="text/babel">

   var Form = React.createClass({

    calculate: function () {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    };
     xhttp.open("GET", "api/values" + "/" + "number" + "/" + "src" + "/" + "aux" + "/" + "dest", true);
     xhttp.send();
    },

     render: function (){
        return (
    <div>
        Number of rings: <input type="number" id="number"/> <br /><br />
        Source: <input type="text" id="src"/><br /><br />
        Auxiliary: <input type="text" id="aux"/><br /><br />
        Destination: <input type="text" id="dest"/><br /><br />
        <button onClick={this.calculate}>Get Result!</button>
    </div>
        );

    }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('form'));

</script>
<div id="form"></div>
<div id="moves"></div>
```

I want the result to be posted in the "moves" div, but can't figure out how. Am I trying to use React in a way it's not supposed to work?

I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct api route

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/values/{number}/{source}/{aux}/{destination}")]
    public string Get(int number, string source, string aux, string destination)
    {
        Hanoi h = new Hanoi();
        return h.MoveDisks(number, source, aux, destination);
    }
```